# Add column to dataframe which is the sd of rnorm from previous columns

Tags: r, function, loops, apply

I have a data frame of two columns

```
set.seed(120)
df <- data.frame(m1 = runif(500,1,30),n1 = round(runif(500,10,25),0))
```

and I wish to add a third column that uses column `n1` and `m1` to generate a normal distribution and then to get the standard deviation of that normal distribution. I mean to use the values in each row of the columns `n1` as the number of replicates (n) and `m1` as the mean.

How can I write a function to do this? I have tried to use apply

```
stdev <- function(x,y) sd(rnorm(n1,m1))
df$Sim <- apply(df,1,stdev)
```

But this does not work. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Many thanks,
Matt

Comment: Thanks - I mean to use the values in each row of the columns n1 as the number of replicates (n) and m1 as the mean. I think that I had not realised that I needed standard deviation too (sd) for rnorm so I might not be able to do what I intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data frame input looks like:

```
# > head(df)
#          m1 n1
# 1 12.365323 15
# 2  4.654487 15
# 3 10.993779 24
# 4 24.069388 22
# 5  6.684450 18
# 6 15.056766 16
```

> I mean to use the values in each row of the columns n1 and m1 as the number of replicates (n) and as the mean.

First show you how to use `apply`:

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) sd(rnorm(n = x[2], mean = x[1])))
```

But a better way is to use `mapply`:

```
mapply(function(x,y) sd(rnorm(n = x, mean = y)), df$n1, df$m1)
```

`apply` is ideal for matrix input; for data frame input you get great overhead for type conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Another option

```
lapply(Map(rnorm,n=df$m1,mean=df$n1),sd)
```